# Google maps no longer work on iPhone Phonagap App

Tags: javascript, iphone, google-maps, gwt, cordova

I have developed a phonegap application in GWT that uses the GWT Api for google maps.
Since recently for iOs5 and iOs6 iphones, the map is no longer displayed, instead I get this message

```
we are sorry but we don't have maps at this zoom level for this region
```

What could be the cause?

I've heard that google-maps are no longer installed in apple devices, but I think that this is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rebuilt the iPhone app and now it works

Answer (score -2):

Counter-offensive from Google?

You don't allow to install our app on your phones, we don't allow your phones to use our API or our site...